# Promise to call google map API nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I want to call this api `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${location}` with location variable using promise in nodejs 
I did that using request and callback but I can't imagine how the code will look like using promise.

[UPDATA]

this is my code but it logs to console no thing

```
function callApi() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        request(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=giza`, 
            function(err, response, body ) {
                resolve(body);
            });  
    });   
}

callApi().then(function(body){
    console.log(body);
    console.log("Gg");
    })
    .catch(function(body) {

    })
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like at the  moment?

Comment: "*would anyone provide me with the code?*" - No. That's not how SO works.

Comment: @Timo I updated the question take a look please

Comment: @Bergi I updates the question

Comment: @shroukmansour Thanks, that looks good. Doesn't it work? (Of course, you're not using the `location` variable, and you always call `resolve` instead of `reject` even when there's an `err`).

Comment: Doesn't look like an issue with the promise to me. Does your call succeed? What's the response HTTP code? You don't specify an API key, could it be that the call fails due to missing authentication?

Comment: I didn't use the http module yet, and it's not because of authentication as I called the same api but using call backs and every thing worked well @Timo

Answer (score -1):

Use [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise) package which uses promises instead of callbacks

Comment: I already use them but I don't know how and my code doesn't work